# laravel How to manage view specific javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

Hi guys this is my first question. 
I'm having trouble on how to organize my javascript with laravel. 
I Have some public java-script which should be included in every page, and some page or view specific scripts. 
my approach now is a separate include file filled with {if} statements wrapping the view specific scripts and I pass the page name to the view to load the appropriate scripts and it look like this.

this is the routing code to get the page name from the url:

```
Route::get('project/{section?}', 'ProjectController@index');
```

this is the controller

```
class ProjectController extends Controller
    {
        //
        public function index($section = 'pitch')
        {
            $page = 'project';
            if ($section == 'pitch') {
                return view('pages.project.pitch', compact('page', 'section'));
            } elseif ($section == 'business_details') {
                return view('pages.project.businessDetails', compact('page', 'section'));
            } elseif ($section == 'marketing_sales') {
                return view('pages.project.marketingSales', compact('page', 'section'));
            } elseif ($section == 'staff') {
                return view('pages.project.staff', compact('page', 'section'));
            } else {
                return view('pages.project.pitch', compact('page', 'section'));
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is a sample{{not the full code !}} of my included scripts.blade.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
@if(isset($page) && $page == 'explore')
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyATVGl-q2F19QoSxS-h1amZLEQ0hzTU3sQ"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
@elseif(isset($page) && $page == 'home')
@elseif(isset($page) && $page == 'project' && $section == 'pitch')
    <script src="/js/pie-chart.js"></script>
@elseif(isset($page) && $page == 'project' && $section == 'business_details')
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyATVGl-q2F19QoSxS-h1amZLEQ0hzTU3sQ"></script>
@elseif(isset($page) && $page == 'project' && $section == 'marketing_sales')
    <script src="/js/pie-chart.js"></script>

@elseif(isset($page) && $page == 'project' && $section == 'staff')
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
@endif
```

this approach is exhausting and it feels like there is a better so is there ?
thanx for ur help in advance

Comment: Add different layouts and extends in you blade

Comment: my layouts are organized good but I guess I was complicating I should @yield my scripts in every view separately, thanx for your comment ♥

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script view:

```
@yield('js-import')
```

And in your view (explore for exemple)

```
@section('js-import')
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyATVGl-q2F19QoSxS-h1amZLEQ0hzTU3sQ"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
@endsection
```

Comment: thanx I guess I was over thinking it or over organizing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have section in your template just for the javascript and then in every view to place the code in the section. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#template-inheritance